# Could you help me to start this demonstration by contrapositive

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic

If a,b,c are positive numbers such that a+b>c, then a>c/2 or b>c/2.

I am quite beginner in demonstrating, by the contrapositive method I know that I must deny both assumptions. help me move forward in this example

Comment: You should check your recitation of proof by contrapositive.  I'm convinced you have swapped "antecedent" and "consequence".  (That is, you have recited the invalid form "proof by converse".)

Answer (score 1):

The negation of ($a>c/2 $or $b>c/2 $) is ($a\le c/2$ and $b\le c/2 )$

The negation of $a+b>c$ is $ a+b\le c$

Thus you need to show if  $a\le c/2$ and $b\le c/2 $ then $ a+b\le c$

Answer (score 1):

The [contrapositive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of "if A then B" is "if not B then not A".

In your case, A is "$a+b>c$", and B is "$a > \frac c2$ or $b>\frac c2$".

The negation of $\left(a>\frac c2 \text{ or } b> \frac c2 \right)$ is $\left( a\leq \frac c2 \text{ and } b\leq \frac c2 \right)$ (neither $a$ or $b$ can be greater than $\frac c2$).

The negation of $a+b>c$ is $a+b\leq c$ (if it's not greater than $c$, it is either less than $c$ or equal to $c$).

You can use this for your proof.